# How can I make JUnit let me set variables in one test case and access them in other if they are in the same class

Tags: junit

Let say I have a test class called MyTest.

In it I have three tests.

```
public class MyTest {

AnObject object;

@Before
public void setup(){
  object = new AnObject();
  object.setSomeValue(aValue);
}

@Test
public void testMyFirstMethod(){
    object.setAnotherValue(anotherValue);
    // do some assertion to test that the functionality works
    assertSomething(sometest);
}

@Test
public void testMySecondMethod(){
    AValue val = object.getAnotherValue();
    object.doSomethingElse(val);
    // do some assertion to test that the functionality works
    assertSomething(sometest);
}
```

Is there any way I can use the value of `anotherValue`, which is set with its setter in the first test, in the second test. I am using this for testing database functionality. When I create an object in the DB I want to get its GUID so I can use this to do updates and deletes in later test methods, without having to hardcode the GUID and therefore making it irrelevant for future use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [TestNG](http://testng.org) if you need this (and I agree it's fairly common in integration testing). TestNG uses the same instance to run your tests, so values stored in fields are preserved between tests, which is very useful when your objects are expensive to create (JUnit forces you to use statics to achieve the same effect, which should be avoided).

Comment: Thanks, I recently moved from TestNG to JUnit (although obviously wasn't an expert) so this will be an easy move.

Answer (score 5):

You are introducing a dependency between two tests. JUnit deliberately does not support dependency between tests, and you can't guarantee the order of execution (except for test classes in a test suite, see my answer to [Has JUnit4 begun supporting ordering of test? Is it intentional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845929/has-junit4-begun-supporting-ordering-of-test-is-it-intentional/7846712#7846712)). So you really want to have dependencies between two test methods:

1. you have to use an intermediate static value
2. as Cedric suggests, use TestNG, which specifically supports dependencies
3. in this case, you can create a method to create the line, and call it from both methods.

I would personally prefer 3, because:

1. I get independent tests, and I can run just the second test (in Eclipse or such like)
2. In my teardown in the class, I can remove the line from the database, the cleanup. This means that whichever test I run, I always start off with the same (known) database state.

However, if your setup is really expensive, you can consider this to be an integration test and just accept the dependency, to save time.

Comment: Hmmmm ... I should use teardown more regularly!

Answer (score 3):

First off, make sure your @Test 's run in some kind of defined order
i.e. @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
In the example below, I'm assuming that test2 will run after test1
To share a variable between them, use a ThreadLocal (from java.lang).
Note that the scope of the ThreadLocal variable is to the thread, so if you are running multiple threads, each will have a copy of 'email' (the static in this case implies that its only global to the thread)

```
private static ThreadLocal<String> email = new ThreadLocal<String>();
@Test
public void test1 {
    email.set("hchan@apache.org);
}

@Test
public void test2 {
   System.out.println(email.get());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not do that. Tests are supposed to be able to run in random order. If you want to test things that depend on one value in the database, you can do that in the @Before code, so it's not all repeated for each test case.

Comment: Wes I get what you're saying. But I think this is the one case where that's not true. Because I'd have to put potentially untested functionality into the @Before code.

Comment: Then make a function to call at the start of all of your tests. You don't want to make it so you can't run tests in parallel.

Comment: Maintaining state is not mutually exclusive with running your tests in parallel, see how TestNG does it (and my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the followup, I like the idea of putting the code in a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

I have found nice solution, just add Before annotation to the previous test!

```
private static String email = null;
@Before
@Test
public void test1 {
    email = "test@google.com"
}

@Test
public void test2 {
   System.out.println(email);
}
```

Comment: This will not work, when there is already a method annotated with @Before in the same class.

Comment: You can allways make it one, at least it is still a solution.

Comment: This worked for me but with JUnit5 you must use: `@BeforeTestMethod`

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, googled until here and the answer didn't serve to you, I'll just leave this: Use @BeforeEach