# How to run JUnit test last - like @Order(999)

Tags: automated-tests

I have 20 tests in one class but one test need to run last. Is there any option how to achieve that? Like annotation @Order(Last) or @Order(999)

Best what I can do is to mark all tests method with @Order(19) to @Order(19) and test that need run last have @Order(100)

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-test-order but also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7845929/11934850

Comment: Each test should be standalone; neither depend on nor influence other tests.